# need Clarification on NSButton Creation and Usage

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I have below code to create simple NSButton in a separate function

```
-(void)myFunction
{
    NSButton *btn = [self createButton:@"Button_Name"];

    if(some condition )
    {
      [btn setEditable:YES];
    }
}

- (NSButton*)createButton:(NSString *)buttonName 
{
    NSButton *btn = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(20, 0, 20, 20)];
    [btn setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    [btn setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
    [btn setTarget:self];
    [btn setTitle: buttonName];

    return btn;
}
```

In my same It is working fine.I am using this code in a Big project.Will It work normally or will cause some problem.Is this a correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things I would like to bring in your notice:

1. You pass `buttonName` and `buttonTitle` but never uses it.
2. You create an object of type `NSButton` but your object name is against the convention, by reading `btnCell` someone will expect it to be `NSButtonCell`.
3. In the above code I cant see any reference to the newly created button and even you are not adding it to any view. (*I hope in your real Big project you are not missing those.*)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.I am not asking about convention,Don't worry I am taking care all those steps in my project.I am asking about the concept buddy :).